# breezejs how to using as datasource

Tags: breeze

i'm using breezejs for some time now, and i'm happy about it and it's rich functionality , but the problem with breezejs is that i cant use it as datasource almost for anything.

there is no grid that you could show data and not losing functionality, and you cant use your array of entities as normal array. (so you cant use it as datasource for dropdown ...)

so for showing data in UI i end up converting data to normal array and losing Breeze functionality (like track change) and before save converting them back.

some code like this one for converting to normal array:

```
  if(data.length>0)
{
       var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data[0]._backingStore);
       var columns: string[] = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
       {
           columns.push(names[i]); //Getting columns name
       }
       var newArray = [];
       data.forEach((item, index, array) => {
            newArray.push(item._backingStore);
       });
}
```

my question is how do you show your data in UI using breezejs properly?
(i'm using angualr (hottowel))

Comment: What are you using with `breezejs` ?

Comment: i tried Kendo, wijmo , open source grid all over internet (like handsontable), and last one  multi select combo box for angular (https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select).

Comment: what about `ng-grid` ?

Comment: it's not about grid only , in other component like drop down problem exists also. i'm seeking for an approach to solve data binding problem.

Comment: well we have a general module service where we retrive general service which will  be used in different page there we use angular http but when in the issue like insert update delete , grid showing we use breezejs with angularjs

Comment: We have same approach, i'm mean  we are currently have a general service for CRUD using breeze, and it's more than fine, the problem  is showing data in UI.

Comment: Would you please be more specific about what isn't working? How does it fail you when you try to use the breeze entities directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to solve issues like this:

1. The grid doesn't like the entityType and entityAspect properties on Breeze entities.
2. This grid doesn't know how to handle Knockout style "properties" that are functions.
3. Creating a POCO object using the Breeze entity's property values disconnects you from the change tracking goodness.

You could try creating your POCO object using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), using the Knockout observable as the property's getter and setter functions.  Here's a simple example:

Typescript + Knockout:

```
class PocoBreezeEntity {
    constructor(private entity: breeze.Entity) {
        entity.entityType.dataProperties.forEach(
            dataProperty => {
                Object.defineProperty(
                    this,
                    dataProperty.name,
                    {
                        get: entity[dataProperty.name],
                        set: entity[dataProperty.name],
                        enumerable: true,
                        configurable: true
                    });
            });
    }
}
```

Typescript + Angular:

```
class PocoBreezeEntity {
    constructor(private entity: breeze.Entity) {
        entity.entityType.dataProperties.forEach(
            dataProperty => {
                Object.defineProperty(
                    this,
                    dataProperty.name,
                    {
                        get: function() { return entity[dataProperty.name]; },
                        set: function(newValue) { entity[dataProperty.name] = newValue; },
                        enumerable: true,
                        configurable: true
                    });
            });
    }
}
```

With this kind of approach you have the benefits of POCO entities without losing the Breeze change tracking.

Comment: thanks for your solution,  but we are using angular (+ typescript). if it's possible alter your solution to match the environment. i'll try too.

Comment: ha, I'm using typescript too, I'll add the typescript code.

Comment: and please remember the angular part (not using knockout) :)

Comment: If using Angular, you're already using defined properties, not property functions so that can't be the problem.

Comment: Might be #1- I've worked with some folks having issues with dumb grids that can't handle the circular refs